# Spring with Hibernate - Use JOOQ?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jooq, hibernate-criteria

I know there are already various comparisons. I am also aware that I can achieve the same result with both. My question is whether Hibernate offers me any advantages over JOOQ when selecting DTOs (**really only related to DTOs, not any entities or specific SQL expressions**)? **I don't mean a nicer syntax, etc. but technical advantages**. For example, if I understand correctly, **Hibernate Criteria queries ignore the cache** and therefore there is no advantage over JOOQ.

Comment: Since I like JOOQ very much, but I already use Hibernate and can achieve the same result with both. I am not sure if it makes sense to use another framework.

Comment: A much more interesting question is what advantages you'll get by using jOOQ for this case rather than Hibernate.

Comment: @LukasEder I have reached just the right person. I don't know JOOQ that well, but what I have seen so far has convinced me very much. But apart from the better syntax and platform-specific functions, I don't (yet) see any advantage. But I would be happy to be enlightened by a counter-question =)

Comment: @LukasEder I thought maybe there is some magic in Hibernate that I do not know.

Comment: I cannot give you an unbiased answer here (I could give you a feature comparison list, but it would still be very biased). Try implementing the same dozen of queries with each and see which one makes you more productive. Both answers can be correct, depending on your background. Once you write complex, dynamic SQL, I'm sure there will be only one winner (jOOQ). As long as you mainly do object graph persistence, and only occasionally "DTO projections", Hibernate will "win".